# Changing VM network without restart the virtual machine in ESXi 7

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtual-machines

I want to change my VM network from CLI.
I managed to do this by editing the .vmx file, but I need to Restart my VM for the changes that will take place.
I tried:
vim-cmd vmsvc/power.off #id
change vmx file
vim-cmd vmsvc/power.on #id

I also tried to use `vim-cmd vmsvc/reload #id` to reload the vmx file, but it does not succeed.
If I run the command: `esxcli network vm list` I get:

World ID  Name  Num Ports  Networks

---

2100862  vm1           1  VLAN110
2100869  vm2           1  VLAN102
2100864  vm9           1  VLAN109

I want to change vm1's Network to VLAN101.
From the Admin UI, I can do it without restarting the VM.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't touch the .vmx file, at least not for such trivial tasks as changing VM network. The proper way to do it is by using VMware's `PowerCLI`. That way the changes can be effective immediately, as if done on the GUI.

`PowerCLI` is a module for Powershell, it adds vmware specific cmdlets. You can also add it to Powershell on Linux, in case you have a Linux workstation.

Have on look on this link, it's about `Set-NetworkAdapter` cmdlet:
[VMware PowerCLI Set-NetworkAdapter](https://vdc-repo.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/6bd6daa3-08a8-4660-9159-23265b9d6c00/4d533cf0-f009-4fa0-8679-8d505fbe846b/doc/Set-NetworkAdapter.html)

---

Up to ESXi 6.7, `vSphere CLI` is also available. It's also a set of commands to manage/administer ESXi and VMs but it's deprecated. It's based on Perl. If you have an up to 6.7 version of ESXi, you can also use this. [vSphere CLI](https://developer.vmware.com/web/tool/6.7/vsphere-cli)

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to change my VM's VLAN from a remote server. 
My first thought was SSH, and then change the network, but the only way I was able to find out how to do this is through the vmx file. Do you know how can I change the VM's network from remote server with python scirpt ?

Comment: Sorry @user2354982, I don't know how you could make changes directly to ESXi using Python. Perhaps other may help. VMware If you are into Perl, Perl SDK is still available for the latest versions of ESXi, still it needs installation. Perhaps setting up a bastion-jump system, a small Linux with Powershell and PowerCLI (or Perl SDK) installed and then connecting to it may be a solution; a complicated one for my tastes.

Comment: If you want to use python you should use vsphere api to change network adapter.